# +2 reputation shown in daily summary, not in list

Tags: bug, reputation, tag-wiki, achievements-dialog

Today, I received +2 reputation on the new [Constructed Language](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/) private beta site, for a [tag wiki edit](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/users/9/glorfindel?tab=reputation) on a tag which is probably now orphaned.

This leads to a strange situation where my 'daily' reputation summary in the achievements dialog shows a +2 for this site, without a corresponding entry in the list. You can see in the screenshot below that other reputation events (association bonus, reputation from an answer) from this site do show up in the list.

[image]

Comment: Well, you do have the +2 for now in your profile, maybe it will be gone in the daily reputation recalc... let's see tomorrow what happens.